# Arnold's Trivium problem 51

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, complex-integration

> Calculate $$ f(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ikx}\frac{1 - e^x}{1+e^x}dx.$$

As far as I know, this is not a function but rather the Fourier transform in tempered distributions.

> 1) What is a **rigorous** proof of Arnold's problem ?
>
> 2) How people usually use and manipulate Fourier Transform of tempered distributions ?

Edit : Thx a lot to joriki and sos440 for two very nice and rigorous proofs.

To summarize,

**joriki**'s idea is to get a regular integral by derivation and then using the Rediues Theorem ;

while **sos440** is removing the 'constant' term that makes the integral diverge and treat it seperatly.

If anyone has another different method, I'd be glad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The poles are at $x=(2n+1)\pi\mathrm i$, and the corresponding residues are $-2\mathrm e^{-(2n+1)\pi k}$. If we ignore issues of convergence, this suggests that the integral is

$$
-4\pi\mathrm i\sum_{n=0}^\infty\mathrm e^{-(2n+1)\pi k}=\frac{-4\pi\mathrm i\mathrm e^{-\pi k}}{1-\mathrm e^{-2\pi k}}=\frac{-2\pi\mathrm i}{\sinh\pi k}\;.
$$

To make this rigorous in the context of tempered distributions, you can take the derivative of the function being Fourier-transformed, calculate the resulting convergent integral, and divide by $-\mathrm ik$ (see [Tempered distributions and Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) at Wikipedia). The residues are slightly more complicated to evaluate, but as one might expect the result is the same.

Comment: The derivative is $\frac{-2e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$ which has no residues. So what is a rigorous proof ? Is it possible to say that your series converges (in tempered distributions) to the fourier transform of the function ?

Comment: @Damien: Why doesn't it have residues? It has two second-order poles; I didn't write out the details but as far as I checked their residues come out right.

Comment: What I meant is that, because the poles are of second-order, then all the residues are zero.

Comment: @DamienL, That a pole is of second order does not imply that the residue is zero, as you can confirm in the case $$ f(z) = \frac{1+z}{z^2}. $$ And in our example, at $z = (2n+1)\pi i$ we have $$ -\frac{2e^{z}}{(1 + e^{z})^2} e^{ikz} = \frac{2 e^{- (2n+1) \pi  k}}{(z-(2n+1) \pi i )^2} + \frac{2 i e^{-(2n+1) \pi  k} k}{z-(2n+1) \pi i } + \cdots. $$

Comment: Ok, very nice !

Answer (score 8):

We divide the integral into two parts:

\begin{align*}
f(k)
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}} \mathrm{sgn}(x) e^{-ikx} \, dx + \int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-ikx} \left( \frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} - \mathrm{sgn}(x) \right) \, dx
\end{align*}

The first one can be easily computed by *integration by parts* as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb{R}} \mathrm{sgn}(x) e^{-ikx} \, dx
&= -\int_{\Bbb{R}} 2\delta(x) \frac{e^{-ikx}}{-ik} \, dx
 = -\frac{2i}{k}.
\end{align*}

Indeed, this manipulation can be justified in the context of tempered distributions. (Just observe what happens when the Fourier transform and the differentiation are interchanged.)

The remaining part is now integrable in ordinary sense, and we have

\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb{R}} e^{-ikx} \left( \frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} - \mathrm{sgn}(x) \right) \, dx
&= 4i \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (kx) \, e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}} \, dx \\
&= 4i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin (kx) \, e^{-nx} \, dx \\
&= 4i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \frac{k}{k^2 + n^2}
\end{align*}

Combining,

\begin{align*}
f(k)
&= -2i \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{k}{n^2 + k^2}
 = -\frac{2\pi i}{\sinh (\pi k)}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Is there an easy way to guess the very last line ?

Comment: @DamienL, It is not an easy identity at all, and actually we need some complex analysis technique or knowledge on Fourier series. One possible way, though neither easy nor elementary, is to began with the Weierstrass factorization of $\sinh x$ given by $$ \frac{\sinh \pi x}{\pi x} = \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{x^2}{n^2} \right). $$

Comment: By the way, I like your answer very much. It is a pitty to end up with a nasty series. There should be an easier way to solve this problem.

Comment: @DamienL I uploaded 2 proofs enjoy

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&\text{Initially, I considered that the integral does not converge because} \\
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {e^{ikx}\frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}dx} \\
&= 2i \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}\sin(kx)dx \\
&\text{given that } f(x) = \frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}\cos(kx) \text{ is odd, while } g(x) = \frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}\sin(kx) \text{ is even.} \\
&\text{Also, because } \lim_{x \to +\infty} \left(\frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}\right) = -1, \\
&\text{I considered that the integral } \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}\sin(kx)dx \text{ diverges.} \\
&\text{In collaboration with my friend Anastasis, we found that things are somewhat different:} \\
&\text{1st solution} \\
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} {e^{ikx}\frac{1 - e^x}{1 + e^x}dx} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {y^{ik}\frac{1 - y}{1 + y}\frac{1}{y}dy} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {y^{ik}\left(\frac{1}{y} - 1\right)\frac{1}{1 + y}dy} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {y^{ik}\left(\frac{1}{y} - 1\right)\left(\int_0^{+\infty} {e^{-(1 + y)x}dx}\right)dy} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {e^{-x}\left(\int_0^{+\infty} {(y^{ik - 1} - y^{ik})e^{-yx}dy}\right)dx} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {e^{-x}\left(\frac{\Gamma(ik)}{x^{ik}} - \frac{\Gamma(ik + 1)}{x^{ik + 1}}\right)dx} \\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} {e^{-x}\left(\frac{\Gamma(ik)}{x^{ik}} - \frac{ik\Gamma(ik)}{x^{ik + 1}}\right)dx} \\
&= \Gamma(ik)\int_0^{+\infty} {\left(x^{-ik} - ikx^{-ik - 1}\right)e^{-x}dx} \\
&= \Gamma(ik)(\Gamma(1 - ik) - ik\Gamma(-ik)) \\
&= \Gamma(ik)(\Gamma(1 - ik) + \Gamma(1 - ik)) \\
&= 2\Gamma(ik)\Gamma(1 - ik) \\
&= \frac{4i\pi}{{\sin(ik\pi)}} \\
&= \frac{4i\pi}{{e^{i(k\pi)} - e^{-i(k\pi)}}} \\
&= \frac{4i\pi}{{e^{-k\pi} - e^{k\pi}}} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
&\text{2nd solution} \\
&\text{Let } f(z) = e^{ikz}\frac{1 - e^z}{e^z + 1}, \text{ analytic in the upper half-plane with poles } z_n = i\pi(2n + 1) \text{ where} \\
&\text{Res}\left(f(z),z_n\right) = e^{iki\pi(2n + 1)}\left(1 - e^{i\pi(2n + 1)}\right)\lim_{z \to i\pi(2n + 1)} \frac{z - i\pi(2n + 1)}{e^z + 1} = -2e^{-k\pi(2n + 1)} \\
&\text{For } z = Re^{i\theta} \text{ with } \theta \in [0,\pi]: f(z) = e^{ikR\cos(\theta)}e^{-kR\sin(\theta)}\frac{1 - e^{R\cos(\theta)}e^{iR\sin(\theta)}}{e^{R\cos(\theta)}e^{iR\sin(\theta)} + 1} \\
&\Rightarrow |f(z)| = e^{-kR\sin(\theta)}\left|\frac{1 - e^{R\cos(\theta)}e^{iR\sin(\theta)}}{e^{R\cos(\theta)}e^{iR\sin(\theta)} + 1}\right| \\
&\leq e^{-kR\sin(\theta)}\frac{\left|1 - e^{R\cos(\theta)}\right|}{|e^{iR\sin(\theta)} + 1|} \xrightarrow{R \to \infty} 0 \\
&\text{If } (c) \text{ is the upper half-circle with diameter AB where } A(-R,0) \text{ and } B(R,0), \\
&\text{then } \int_c f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum_{n=1}^\infty \text{Res}\left(f(z), z_n\right) \text{ and } R \to +\infty \text{ we have} \\
&\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{ikx}\frac{1 - e^x}{e^x + 1}dx = 2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(-2e^{-k\pi(2n + 1)}\right) \\
&= -4i\pi\frac{e^{-k\pi}}{1 - e^{-2k\pi}} = \frac{4i\pi}{{e^{-k\pi} - e^{k\pi}}} \\
\end{align*}